# How to return a primitive property value with CALayer's "+ (id) defaultValueForKey", etc?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, core-animation, calayer, kvc

So.. `CALayer` KVC "extensions" handle all the weirdo's... such as..

```
+ (id) defaultValueForKey: (NSString*)key    {
   return [key isEqualToString:@"borderColor"] 
        ? (id)cgPINK 
        : [super defaultValueForKey:key];    }
```

And [Apple's Docs allude](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) to how best to encode a struct, when they refer to the default value if you DON'T provide a value...

> For example, if the value for key is a CGSize struct, the method returns a size struct containing (0.0,0.0) wrapped in an NSValue object.

However, I can't figure out how to provide ***normal, stinking, primitives***, i.e. `CGFloat`

I've tried `@VAL`-type `NSNumber` encoding,

<s>`return ![key isEqualToString:@"lineWidth"] ?: @3;`</s>

and with no viable `NSValue` methods, even a desperate attempt to cast them to `id`

<s>`return ![key isEqualToString:@"zPosition"] ?: (id)262453;`</s>`// lol`

What's the deal?  Is this just an "oh-well, ya can't" situation due to CALayer's odd-ball nature?  An obvious solution I have embarrassingly overlooked?  Or is it just a shady API - that refuses to document it's own shortcomings?

Comment: Does NSNumber numberWithFloat: or numberWithInt not work?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to return an NSNumber.

I haven't yet tried using Objective C literals. Skip that for now to limit the complications. Just use code like this:

```
return [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 3.0];
```

or numberWithBool, or numberWithInt, or whatever is appropriate.